# Spring security url pattern matching

Tags: spring, spring-security

- `<a href="/my/edit.htm?ServiceRequestId=${history.serviceRequestId}">`Edit`</a>` / `<a href="/my/delete.htm?id=${history.serviceRequestId}">`Delete`</a>`

What should be pattern for above URL.I am using following but its not working

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/register*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/my/*" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/my/*\?param=value" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
```

---

Comment: href="/my/edit.htm?ServiceRequestId=${history.serviceRequestId}">Edit</a> / <a href="/my/delete.htm?id=${history.serviceRequestId}">Delete

Comment: <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/register*" access="permitAll" />
        
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
               <intercept-url pattern="/my/*" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
               <intercept-url pattern="/my/*\?param=value" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />

Comment: Please tell me the right pattern which will work in above case

Answer (score 0):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/my/**" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
```

should work, but notice that this will match something that is `<root of the project>/my/something` . The above links are relative and may result in some other url will be not mached. To ensure you start from the root you can use `c:url` if you are in jsp.

Comment: Please answer the below question

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Form .I want to update the request made by customer by changing its status.some of field coming form controller .I want to submit form to controller in order to acess the values

```
h2>Update Request</h2>
>form:form method="POST" action="/my/update.htm" commandName="servicehistory">
table align="center" border="0">

<tr><td>Request Id: </td>
<td><form:input path="sr.ServiceRequestId" value="${sr.serviceRequestId}"></form:input>     < other fields..............
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td></tr>
```

> Controller which access the form value and update the request in database.but it is not happening.GUI displays resource is not available.It was working without Spring Security.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/update.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)


public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("servicehistory") @Valid ServiceHistories sh1,BindingResult result,ModelMap map)

{

  Redirect it to another page after validating the form
    return new ModelAndView(("redirect:/displaylist.htm"));
}

>Spring Security which implement security after matching url and user role
```

< http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('Technician')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/my/**" access="hasRole('Techincian')" />
```

Comment: Try to wrap the action url in the form in c:url.

Answer (score 0):

This is JSp page that is used to assign the compalint to techincian. After hitting submit, it give number format exceptions.

```
<c:forEach items="${hlist}" var="history" varStatus="i">
<tr>
<td><form:input path="requests[${i.index}].ServiceRequestId" value="${history.serviceRequestId }"></form:input></td>

<td><form:input path="requests[${i.index}].Description"  value="${history.description }"></form:input></td>
<td><form:select multiple="false" path="requests[${i.index}].userto.UserId">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />

             <c:forEach items="${user}" var="u" varStatus="index">                   
                     <form:option label="${u.userName}" value="${u.userId}" />

                   </c:forEach>
                     </form:select>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<tr><td> <input type="submit" value="Assign Technicians"></td></tr>


>Controller : I am using Autopopulating list to access list coming from above form.But it gives Number format exception. But it is working for another scenario which is identical to this one.
@ModelAttribute("requestForm")
    public RequestForm getRequest()
    {
        RequestForm rf=new RequestForm();
        rf.setRequests(new AutoPopulatingList(ServiceRequests.class));
        return rf;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/assigntech.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String assign(@ModelAttribute("requestForm") RequestForm requestForm,BindingResult result,ModelMap map)
    {
        List<ServiceRequests> sr=(List<ServiceRequests>)requestForm.getRequests();
        System.out.println(sr.size());
        System.out.println(sr.get(0).getUserto().getUserId());

        return "Welcome";
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21203804/edit) your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

To match everything under a folder like /my/, you should use double star ** because the pattern matching follows Ant standard.